# Add contents to ZIP without full path not working

Tags: php, linux, zip

I am creating Epub package which I need to pack in the following order

```
$dest = "ebooks/pack/";
exec("zip -DX0 ".$dest."/book.zip ".$dest."/mimetype ");
exec("zip -DrX9 ".$dest."/book.zip ".$dest."/META-INF ".$dest."/OEBPS");
```

So I when I pack this , Zip archive structure looks like below

```
ebooks/pack/mimetype 
ebooks/pack/META-INF
ebooks/pack/OEBPS
```

But I need that files to be in home , For example when I un compress It should look like below

```
mimetype 
META-INF
OEBPS
```

I also tried to navigate via `cd  ebooks/pack/` , that throws the error

```
zip warning: name not matched: mimetype
```

I even used full path like `home/user/public_html/ful`

```
exec("cd home/sam/public_html/domain.com/".$dest."/; zip -DX0 ".$dest."/book.zip  mimetype 2&1",$output);
```

I even tried `chdir` , It displays the correct path where my files are there

```
echo getcwd() . "\n";
chdir('home/sam/public_html/domain.com/".$dest."/');
echo getcwd() . "\n";
```